# How to add multiple values inside the same tag of xml generated using xml.etree.ElementTree in Python?

Tags: python, xml

I am generating **XML file** using *xml.etree.ElementTree* in **Python**.

There is one tag in which I have to add multiple values by iterating through a for loop.

Currently only single value is getting added to that tag. This tag will display the information of all the software installed on the system which I am getting using ***import wmi***.

The script look as follows:

```
    ##Here starts populating elements inside xml file
    top = Element('my_practice_document')
    comment = Comment('details')
    top.append(comment)
    child = SubElement(top, 'my_information')
    childs = SubElement(child,'my_name')
    childs.text = str(options.my_name)
    child = SubElement(top, 'sys_info')

    #Following section is for retrieving list of software installed on the system
    import wmi
    w = wmi.WMI()
    for p in w.Win32_Product():
        if (p.Version is not None) and (p.Caption is not None):
            print p.Caption + " version "+ p.Version      
           child.text =  p.Caption + " version "+ p.Version
```

So, in the above script you can have a look in the section where list of software installed on system is retrieved.

The tag sys_info should have all details of software installed and the xml should look as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <my_document>
      <my_information>
        <my_name>False</my_name>
      </my_information>
      <sys_info>microsoft office version 123</sys_info>
      <sys_info>skype version 12.0.30723</sys_info>
      ..
      ..
      ..
      ..
    </my_document>
```

**So, please suggest how can I have sys_info tag consisting of all the details of system software installed??**

Answer (score 0):

Just try to move the logic for creating new `<sys_info>` elements into the `for` loop body :

```
import wmi
w = wmi.WMI()
for p in w.Win32_Product():
    if (p.Version is not None) and (p.Caption is not None):
        child = SubElement(top, 'sys_info') 
        child.text =  p.Caption + " version "+ p.Version
```